# Synonyms in QnA Maker

Tags: synonym, azure-qna-maker

How can I make QnAMaker recognize synonyms in the questions asked in order to help it return the correct answer. For example, the word disbursement and distribution in my work mean the same thing. Is there a way to ensure that QnA maker will understand each.

Comment: Thank you, but the number of questions grows exponentially if I have to include every synonym of words like 'the, an, a' or 'is, was, were, are' etc. Just writing something as simple as "What are fees?" becomes a huge issue.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is include the phrases as individual questions for that particular "answer". As you can see from the included image, you can enter an initial phrase (aka question) and then enter additional phrases by clicking "Add alternative phrases". Both of 
these phrases are then associated to the one provided answer.

Hope of help!

---

[image]

[image]